# Difference between Eulers product and Zeta Function at a finite values

Tags: calculus, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, euler-product

So a very important formula proven by Euler is that
[image]

is equal to

[image]

Of course these formulas give you the same value when they reach infinity, but my question is that say $s=1$. What would be the difference in values between these two formulas if n and p didn't go to infinity and instead stopped at any finite would they always be very close or would there difference become greater and greater.

Comment: A reasonable question is: how do you want the values you stop at to relate? If you take the product of primes up to $P$ and the sum of reciprocals up to $N$, how do you want $P$ to relate to $N$?

Comment: I mean that p and n would be the same value

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that the two values
$$ \sum_{n \leq P} \frac{1}{n^s}, \qquad \prod_{p \leq P} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1}$$
are very different for all $s > 1$.

But there is something that can be said. For the rest of this answer, I will instead answer the following question:

> Suppose we consider the Euler product of primes up to $P$,
>   $$ \prod_{p \leq P} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p^s} \right) ^{-1}.$$
>   What sort of sum (as in, what set of integers $\mathcal{N}$ should we sum over) so that
>   $$ \sum_{n \in \mathcal{N}} \frac{1}{n^s}$$
>   is very near the Euler product?

I think this is at the heart of your question. In answering this question, I will inadvertently provide an answer to your original question, which (seems to) consider $\mathcal{N} = [1, P]\cap\mathbb{Z}$.

A single factor in the Euler product looks like
$$ \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{p^s}}.$$
This can be expanded as a geometric series into
$$ \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{p^s}} = 1 + p^{-s} + p^{-2s} + p^{-3s} \cdots$$
This converges absolutely for $s > 0$. If we take this product with the factor corresponding to another prime $q$, then we get
$$ \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{p^s}} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{q^s}} = (1 + p^{-s} + p^{-2s} + \cdots)(1 + q^{-s} + q^{-2s} + \cdots).$$
In the expansion of the terms on the right, we can form $n^{-s}$ for exactly those integers $n$ of the form $n = p^j q^k$, namely by multiplying the $j$th term in the first sum by the $k$th term in the second.
So
$$\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{p^s}} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{q^s}} = \sum_{n \in \mathcal{N}_{p,q}} \frac{1}{n^s},$$
where $\mathcal{N}_{p,q}$ denotes exactly those integers formed from the primes $p$ and $q$.

More generally but in the same vein, we have
$$ \prod_{p \in \mathcal{P}} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1} = \sum_{n \in \mathcal{N}_{\mathcal{P}}} \frac{1}{n^s},$$
where $\mathcal{P}$ is a collection of primes and $\mathcal{N}_{\mathcal{P}}$ denotes the set of integers formed from products of primes in $\mathcal{P}$.

To answer my question, the right $\mathcal{N}$ is the set of integers formed from the primes up to $P$, in which case there is an exact equality. Note that this is an infinite sum!

This also means that
$$ \prod_{p \leq P} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1} - \sum_{n \leq P} \frac{1}{n^s} = \sum_{\substack{n > P \\ n \in \mathcal{N}_{p \leq P}}} \frac{1}{n^s} - \sum_{\substack{n \leq P \\ n \not \in \mathcal{N}_{p \leq P}}} \frac{1}{n^s}.$$

Comment: maybe a typo $\sum_k p^{-sk}$ converges for $Re(s) > 0$, but you also didn't prove that the Euler product is valid only for $Re(s) > 1$ because there $\sum_n n^{-s}$ is an absolutely convergent series, and  since $\prod_{p < P} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}} = \sum_n n^{-s} 1_{n \in \mathcal{N}_{p \le P}}$ is just a different order for summing $(n^{-s})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, and that for absolutely convergent series the order of summation doesn't matter, we get that $\prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}} = \sum_n n^{-s}$ for $Re(s) > 1$

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, that's true! I corrected the statement about convergence, and continue to brush aside any statement about convergence of the full Euler product itself. Thank you!